# User logout after the first access token expires in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

The user is logout after the first access token expires.

How do I automatically create and set a new access token after it has expired?

Comment: You juste have to fetch a new access token again ...

Comment: It works fine for the postman, but I don't know how to implement it in the code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just customize the TokenRefreshView method

### views

In the program you are building, go to the views section and add the following class.

```
class CustomTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])

        # set Refresh and Access token in browser with Httponly cookie.
        response = Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        response.set_cookie(
            key=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH'],
            value=serializer.validated_data["refresh"],
            domain=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN'],
            path=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_PATH'],
            expires=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
            secure=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
            httponly=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
            samesite=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAME_SITE']
        )
        response.set_cookie(
            key=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'],
            value=serializer.validated_data["access"],
            domain=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN'],
            path=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_PATH'],
            expires=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
            secure=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
            httponly=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
            samesite=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAME_SITE']
        )
        return response
```

### URLs

for class-based views

**views.CustomTokenRefreshView.as_view()**

```
    path('token/refresh/', views.CustomTokenRefreshView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
    path('token/verify/', TokenVerifyView.as_view(), name='token_refresh'),
```

### Middleware

Of course, you have to add the following as well.

Create a file called middleware.py in the program you are building, then add these two custom classes.

```
class MoveJWTCookieIntoTheBody(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    for Django Rest Framework JWT's POST "/token-refresh" endpoint --- check for a 'token' in the request.COOKIES
    and if, add it to the body payload.
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        super().__init__(get_response)
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        if request.path == '/auth/token/verify/' and settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS'] in request.COOKIES:

            if request.body != b'':
                data = json.loads(request.body)
                data['token'] = request.COOKIES[settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS']]
                request._body = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')


class MoveJWTRefreshCookieIntoTheBody(MiddlewareMixin):
    """
    for Django Rest Framework JWT's POST "/token-refresh" endpoint --- check for a 'token' in the request.COOKIES
    and if, add it to the body payload.
    """

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        super().__init__(get_response)
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, *view_args, **view_kwargs):
        if request.path == '/auth/token/refresh/' and settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH'] in request.COOKIES:

            if request.body != b'':
                data = json.loads(request.body)
                data['refresh'] = request.COOKIES[settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH']]
                request._body = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
```

### Settings

Then you have to add these in the settings.

```
import datetime

...

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'accounts.middleware.MoveJWTCookieIntoTheBody',
    'accounts.middleware.MoveJWTRefreshCookieIntoTheBody'
]

...

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': False,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': False,
    'UPDATE_LAST_LOGIN': False,

    'ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'SIGNING_KEY': settings.SECRET_KEY,
    'VERIFYING_KEY': None,
    'AUDIENCE': None,
    'ISSUER': None,
    'JWK_URL': None,
    'LEEWAY': 0,

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('Bearer',),
    'AUTH_HEADER_NAME': 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION',
    'USER_ID_FIELD': 'id',
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'user_id',
    'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULE': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.default_user_authentication_rule',

    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),
    'TOKEN_TYPE_CLAIM': 'token_type',

    'JTI_CLAIM': 'jti',

    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_EXP_CLAIM': 'refresh_exp',
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'SLIDING_TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),

    # Custom_SIMPLE_JWT
    'AUTH_COOKIE': 'token',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_ACCESS': 'access',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_REFRESH': 'refresh',  # Cookie name. Enables cookies if value is set.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_DOMAIN': None,  # A string like "example.com", or None for standard domain cookie.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE': False,  # Whether the auth cookies should be secure (https:// only).
    'AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY': True,  # Http only cookie flag.It's not fetch by javascript.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_PATH': '/',  # The path of the auth cookie.
    'AUTH_COOKIE_SAME_SITE': 'Lax',  # Whether to set the flag restricting cookie leaks on cross-site requests.
    # This can be 'Lax', 'Strict', or None to disable the flag.
}
```

> The only problem is that it gives a new access_token whenever it is reloaded.
>
> > What do you think should be done?

Comment: This could do with a better explanation, but works well. Thanks!